# Is it possible to rename PascalCase1.wav to kebab-case-1.wav with a single perl regex?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sh, regex-lookarounds

Here is a sample of my data:

```
SomePascalCase.wav
ThingsThat1.wav
Are.wav
Here.wav
```

Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
some-pascal-case.wav
things-that-1.wav
are.wav
here.wav
```

Here is what I used:

```
for f in *.wav; do
   mv "$f" $(
      echo "$f" |
      perl -pe 's/([A-Z])([a-z]+)(?=[0-9A-Z])/\L\1\2-/g' |
      perl -pe 's/([A-Z])([a-z]+)(?=.wav)/\L\1\2/g'
   )
done
```

Is it possible to consolidate the two regular expressions I used into a single one?

Comment: You should not use `\1` and `\2` in the replacement expression; you should use `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: IIRC, perl REs are Turing complete, so you can do literally anything with a single RE. Should you, though... of course that's another question entirely.

Comment: There's a bug in your pattern. You want `\.wav`, not `.wav`

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't really use a regex substitution here.  You would use `split` and then `join` with dashes.  The `split` pattern is a negative look behind followed by a look ahead.

```perl
lc join "-", split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/;
```

For example

```perl
pp split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/, "FooBarBaz"

("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
```

Depending on your rules for seperating out numbers, you would just add more boundary checks with look arounds.

```perl
pp split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[\d])|(?<=[\d])(?=[A-Za-z])/, "Foo1BarBaz1"

("Foo", 1, "Bar", "Baz", 1)
```

EDIT
To incorporate this into your one liner, you would do this:

```sh
f=FooBarBaz1
echo $( echo "$f" | perl -pe '$_ = lc join "-", split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[\d])|(?<=[\d])(?=[A-Za-z])/;' )

foo-bar-baz-1
```

Doing it with substitutions will just make it more complicated.

HTH

Comment: none of these commands work in bash or zsh. i also want to use s/pattern/replacement/ so this does not answer my question.

Comment: I updated the answer to use your command line.

Comment: If you want to use something like `pp`, tell people what it is. Since you're merely printing a list here, I don't see an advantage to extra, non-core Perl stuff.

Comment: I don't disagree with you on that but I just left it because it was merely an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your requirements:

- It must work in `bash` as a one-liner.
- It converts the string of filename with a single s/pattern/replacement/ operator.

Then how about:

```
for f in *.wav; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | perl -pe 's/(^|[a-z])([A-Z0-9])/ $1 eq "" ? lc($2) : $1 . "-" . lc($2) /ge')"; done
```

- The `e` option to the `s/pattern/replacement/` operator enables the replacement to be an expression of `perl`.

Comment: thanks! i didn't know you could use sprintf in a perl regex like that. neat!

Comment: Yes. I've added a brief explanation about the `e` option. BR.

Comment: `s/.../.../` is basically short for `s/.../ "..." /e`. You can put any code in the *replacement expression* (not in the regex).

Comment: The `sprintf` was completely useless, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
perl -pe 's/([A-Z])([a-z]+)(?=[0-9A-Z])/\L\1\2-/g' |
perl -pe 's/([A-Z])([a-z]+)(?=.wav)/\L\1\2/g'
```

can be reduced to the nearly equivalent

```sh
perl -pe's/[a-z]\K[A-Z\d]/-$&/g; s/[A-Z]/\L$&/g'
```

or just

```sh
perl -pe's/[a-z]\K[A-Z\d]/-$&/g; $_=lc'
```

(Technically, you can even remove that space.)

For example,

```
$ echo FooBar1.wav | perl -pe's/[a-z]\K[A-Z\d]/-$&/g; $_=lc'
foo-bar-1.wav
```

---

For 100% equivalence, you would need

```sh
perl -pe's/([A-Z][a-z]+)(?:(?=[A-Z\d])|(?=(\.wav)))/ "\L$1" . ( $2 ? "" : "-" ) /eg'
```

(You can even remove all these spaces too.)

For example,

```
$ echo ABCdef.wav | perl -pe's/([A-Z][a-z]+)(?:(?=[A-Z\d])|(?=(\.wav)))/ "\L$1" . ( $2 ? "" : "-" ) /eg'
ABcdef.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

If need to get this inside one substitution command, it could be done like this:

```sh
perl -pe 's/.+?(?=[A-Z0-9.])/($i++?"-":"").lc$&/ge'
```

This matches any set of characters which is followed by a capital, digit, or dot.  The conditional checks if this is the first match or a later one.  If a later one, it prepends a hyphen to the lowercased version of the matched substring.